# What is the Code Definition Window in Visual C++ 2008 Express?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am working on the Sphere Online Judge problems (OK I am only on my 2nd lol) and using VC++ 2008 express and have just noticed the "code definition window". What exactly does this thing do? Is it any use to a beginner like me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code definition window gives you additional context for the code you have the cursor over.

For example if you have the cursor over `Cat` in the following code:

```
Cat c;
```

Then it will display the definition of the `Cat` class in the code definition window.

If you have the following code:

```
c.meow();
```

And you have the cursor over c, it will show you where c was defined.  (i.e. the line of code: `Cat c;`)

---

Instead of using this window, you can simply right click on any part of code and select `go to definition`.

Comment: Perfect, thankyou!
This window makes far more sense when I have the curser over one of my functions, compared to std::cout lol.

Comment: I can't believe I never knew about or used that window before.

Comment: I always find myself saying that about Visual Studio.  Better break out the Visual Studio Hacks Oreilly book :)

Comment: "F12" should bring one to the definition as well.

Answer (score 1):

> The Code Definition window is a read-only editor view that displays the definition of a symbol in a code file stored in, or referenced by, the active project. To display this window, select Code Definition Window from the View menu. When the window first opens, it displays the definition for the last symbol selected. If no definition is available, No definition selected is displayed. This window can be docked along any convenient edge of the integrated development environment (IDE). By default, it is displayed beneath the Code Editor.

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5yx24a6%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The Code Definition window is a read-only editor view that displays the definition of a symbol in a code file stored in, or referenced by, the active project.

It is a way to see the underlying code of a definition in your project (a method, property or constructor, etc.) without having to load up the project containing the code into Visual Studio, and hunting for the symbol.